# Sequence contains no elements error when reading metadata

Tags: kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor Auth Services and trying to get it to work with Thinktecture Identity Server.  I am getting this error when reading the metadata:

Sequence contains no elements

Here is the code that I am using in the Startup.cs file:

```
        var authServicesOptions = new Kentor.AuthServices.Owin.KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
        {
            SPOptions = new SPOptions
            {
                EntityId = new EntityId("https://dev.identity.research.ufl.edu:4432/AuthServices")
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            AuthenticationType = "saml2p",
            Caption = "SAML2p",
        };

        authServicesOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
          new EntityId("urn:edu:ufl:dev:00856"),
          authServicesOptions.SPOptions)
        {
            MetadataLocation = "https://dev.identity.research.ufl.edu:4432/EMvc/Metadata.txt",               
        });

        app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(authServicesOptions);
```

Also I'm including the error message and part of the stack trace below.

Thanks very much for any help you can provide in how I should troubleshoot this error.

Sincerely,
Cheryl Bearden

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +310
   Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider.ReadMetadataIdpDescriptor(ExtendedEntityDescriptor metadata) +108
   Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider.ReadMetadata(ExtendedEntityDescriptor metadata) +132
   Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider.DoLoadMetadata() +127
   Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider.ReloadMetadataIfRequired() +169
   Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider.CreateAuthenticateRequest(AuthServicesUrls authServicesUrls) +73
   Kentor.AuthServices.WebSso.SignInCommand.InitiateLoginToIdp(IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData, AuthServicesUrls urls, IdentityProvider idp, Uri returnUrl) +36
   Kentor.AuthServices.WebSso.SignInCommand.Run(EntityId idpEntityId, String returnPath, HttpRequestData request, IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData) +447
   Kentor.AuthServices.Owin.d__1.MoveNext() +781